# My program crashes whenever i try to delocate the old memory

Tags: c

so basically there is a function that allocates a new pointer memory and when i try to delocate the old one the program basically crashes [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJkJC.png)

```
char** AddingToTheBook(char** original, int* size, char *number)
{
    char** newArray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(*size));
    //allocating and copying the values
    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    {
        *(newArray + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(*(original + i))));
        strcpy(*(newArray + i), *(original + i));
    }

    //allocating a new memory to the new number
    *(newArray + (*size)) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(number));
    strcpy(*(newArray + (*size)), number);
    (*size)++;
    //delocating the allocated memories 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(original[i]);
    free(original);

    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: post as a text not the image

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Did you step through the code in a debugger?  That is the first thing to do

Comment: And you do not need or should not cast `malloc` in C

Comment: Compile with warnings, one of them will tell you about the comparison between integer and pointer - that's the bug.

Answer (score 0):

1. `strlen` only returns the number of chars. Make room for the ending zero

   `*(newArray + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(*(original + i))) +1);`
2. Better to `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`
3. How can you go `*size` ahead in `newArray`:

   `*(newArray + (*size)) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(number));`

   You can only go `*size -1` ahead, since it starts from zero.
4. In the `for` loop, it seems you forgot to add the asterisk `*`

   `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Comment: Blindly replacing `strcpy()` with `strncpy()` is dangerous.  `strncpy()` doesn't guarantee the copied-to string is terminated with a nul character.

Comment: point 2. strncpy is more dangerous, but in this case it strlen is the best. You have allocated enough space

Answer (score 0):

You are freeing too much of your original memory.

Look at the for loop when you're freeing the memory:

```
(*size)++;
//delocating the allocated memories 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    free(original[i]);
```

Since `size` is a `int *` you will end up with a very big number of iterations which will free to free much more memory than you allocated. To fix this do the following:

```
(*size)++;
//delocating the allocated memories 
for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
    free(original[i]);
```

Now you're still freeing one element too much since you've incremented *size when adding a new element. The final version to free the original memory is

```
(*size)++;
//delocating the allocated memories 
for (int i = 0; i < *size - 1; i++)
    free(original[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use realloc instead

```
char** AddingToTheBook(char** original, size_t oldsize, char *number)
{
    char** tmp = realloc(**original, (oldsize  + 1) * sizeof(char *));

    if(tmp)
    {
        tmp[oldsize] = malloc(strlen(number) + 1'
        if(tmp[oldsize])
        {
            strcpy(tmp[oldsize], number);
        }
        else
        {
            /* do something for example realloc back to the old size */
            tmp = NULL;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

---

example correct usage

```
    char **tmp = AddingToTheBook(book, size, "Test String")

    if(tmp)
    {
        book = tmp;
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        /* do something adding to book failed */
    }
```

Comment: Does this have a memory leak if `realloc` fails?

Comment: No it returns null then but the original pointer passed to the functions is retained. No danger if correctly used